# GeoTools decode FeatureType

Tags: java, geotools, encoding, xsd

### Encode:

1- A way of encoding a `FeatureType` is :

```
SimpleFeatureType TYPE = DataUtilities.createType("Location", "geom:Point,name:String");
GML encode = new GML(Version.GML2);
encode.setBaseURL(new URL("http://localhost/"));
encode.encode(System.out, TYPE);
```

2- Another way of encoding:

```
 FeatureTypeTransformer t = new FeatureTypeTransformter();
 t.transform(TYPE,System.out);
```

### Decode:

I have a xsd of a featuretype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:complexType xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="jahanserver:test1_Type">
<xs:complexContent>
    <xs:extension base="gml:AbstractFeatureType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="the_geom" minOccurs="1" nillable="false" type="gml:GeometryAssociationType"/>
            <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" nillable="false">
                <xs:simpleType>
                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                        <xs:maxLength value="2147483647"/>
                    </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:extension>
</xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

And I want to decode it as a `SimpleFeatureType`. How can I do that?

**Possible solution 1:**
The [`GML2ParsingUtils`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/extension/xsd/xsd-gml2/src/main/java/org/geotools/gml2/bindings/GML2ParsingUtils.java) Class may be helpful. It has a method named `featuretype` for parsing schema, but I don't know how to prepare the method arguments.

**Possible solution 2:**

```
GML gml = new GML(GML.Version.GML2);
gml.decodeSimpleFeatureType(url,name);
```

But I don't have any url. I have a `HttpServletRequest` containing a bare featuretype with `complexType` xml root.

Answer (score 2):

The easy way is to go with option 2 and the URL it wants is the location of the **XSD** file which will be in the top of the **GML** that is within your `ServletRequest`. So you need to open the root element and extract the namespaces and schema URLs.

Then you can create the name and URL from that:

```
GML gml = new GML(Version.WFS1_0);
gml.setCoordinateReferenceSystem( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84 );

Name typeName = new NameImpl("http://www.openplans.org/topp", "states");
SimpleFeatureType featureType = gml.decodeSimpleFeatureType(schemaLocation, typeName );
```

Alternatively you can go through the hassle of parsing the XML yourself and then use option 1 to extract the schema from the W3C Node you have:

```
schema = GML2ParsingUtils.featureType(node);
```

Comment: The xsd does not contain any urls. See the xsd in the question body

Comment: the URL points to the XSD - the GML contains this

Comment: iant! the request body is a bare featuretype (as I mentioned in the question).I want only decode a featuretype, not a feature!

Comment: then look in decodeSimpleFeatureType and see what it does with the URL's inputstream and copy that

Comment: It is hard!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In that case use GML2ParsingUtils.featureType(Node node) then all you need to do is set up a parser and convert your string into an XML Node.

Comment: That's a good way. please give some details. Enhance your answer

Comment: iant! The `GML2ParsingUtils.featureType(node)` does not accept W3C Node. It accepts `org.geotools.xml.Node`.

Comment: iaint! Can you pay some more attention to this question, please. I need the answer